# Sums of Fourth Powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, perfect-powers

While fooling around on my calculator I found:

$$7^4 + 8^4 + (7 + 8)^4 = 2 * 13^4$$
$$11^4 + 24^4 + (11 + 24)^4 = 2 * 31^4$$

I'm intrigued but I can't explain *why* these two equations are true. Are these coincidences or is there a formula/theorem explaining them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_triple#Triangles_with_an_angle_of_120.C2.B0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a disguised version of triangles with integer sides and one $120^\circ$ angle. These are
$$ 3,5,7 $$
$$ 7,8,13 $$
$$ 5,16,19$$
$$ 11,24, 31,  $$

which solve
$$ a^2 + ab + b^2 = c^2. $$
Square both sides and then double both sides and you get your identities.

These can be generated by a coprime pair of number $m,n$ with
$$ a = m^2 - n^2 $$
$$ b = 2mn+n^2  $$
$$ c = m^2 + mn + n^2 $$

Comment: Since the angle opposite the $c$ side is 120° it's natural to wonder if there exist triplets of these triplets of the form $\{(d_0, d_1, c_0), (d_1, d_2, c_1), (d_2, d_0, c_2)\}$ that can be combined into a triangle with sides $(c_0, c_1, c_2)$ and [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) distances $(d_0, d_1, d_2)$. The answer is yes, the smallest examples being $\{(195, 264, 399), (264, 325, 511), (325, 195, 455)\}$ and $\{(264, 325, 511), (325, 440, 665), (440, 264, 616)\}$.

Comment: (cont) I _assume_ that there are an infinite number of such triangles, but I have no proof of that statement; I found those solutions by a semi-brute-force search.

Comment: @PM2Ring: There are infinitely many such triangles. Kindly see this related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681753/on-a-remarkable-system-of-fourth-powers-using-x4y4xy4-2z4).

Answer (score 9):

First, observe $$\begin{align*}a^{4}+b^{4}+(a+b)^{4}&=2a^{4}+4a^{3}b+6a^{2}b^{2}+4ab^{3}+2b^{4}\\&=2(a^{4}+2a^{3}b+3a^{2}b^{2}+2ab^{3}+b^{4})\\&=2(a^{2}+ab+b^{2})^{2}\end{align*}$$
Your identities arise when $a^{2}+ab+b^{2}$ is itself a perfect square. Solutions to this equation are generated similarly to pythagorean triples: we paramaterise by coprime integers $m,n$. $$\begin{align*}a&=m^{2}-n^{2}\\b&=2mn+n^{2}\end{align*}$$
Your examples are the cases $(m,n)=(3,1)$ and $(5,1)$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start at
Will Jagy's hint.

If
$c^2
=a^2+ab+b^2
$,

$\begin{array}\\
c^4
&=a^4+a^2b^2+b^4+2a^3b+2a^2b^2+2ab^3\\
&=a^4+3a^2b^2+b^4+2a^3b+2ab^3\\
\text{so}\\
2c^4
&=2a^4+6a^2b^2+2b^4+4a^3b+4ab^3\\
&=a^4+b^2+a^4+6a^2b^2+b^4+4a^3b+4ab^3\\
&=a^4+b^4+a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4\\
&=a^4+b^4+(a+b)^4\\
\end{array}
$

Yep.